# Counting the no of records and inserting it into an temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table A**

```
agent_pay  status_ind  policy_number  company_code
---------  ----------  ------------- --------------
1011        B            001            06
1012        B            002            06
1013        B            003            06
1014        B            004            06
1015        B            005            06        
1016        B            006            06
```

**TABLE B**

```
agent_pay   policy_number   service_ind
---------   -------------   ------------
1011          001                 X
1012          001                 S
1013          003                 X
1014          004                 S
1011          007                 X
1011         008                  S
```

There are two tables.First I want to check the count of policies against the agent in both the tables.If the count matches in both the table,it will show which policies are matched against the agent.The matched data will go into an  temporary table.If it doesn't matches,it will go into an error table.I have tried the below query:

```
    (select a.agent_pay,count(policy_number) 
from table1 a group by a.agent_pay)
    intersect
    (select b.agent,count(policy_number) 
from table2 b where service_ind='x' group by b.agent)
```

Please help me how can i insert the data into an temporary table in SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

--Please try this query

```
create table tableA ( agent_pay int,  status_ind char(1), policy_number char(3),  company_code char(2))
go
insert into tableA 
VALUES (1011,'B',            '001',            '06'),
(1012,'B',            '002',            '06'),
(1013,'B',            '003',            '06'),
(1014,'B',            '004',            '06'),
(1015 ,'B',            '005',            '06'),        
(1016 ,'B',            '006',            '06')
go
create table tableB (agent_pay int, policy_number char(3), service_ind char(1))
INSERT INTO TABLEB
VALUES
(1011          ,'001',                 'X')
,(1012          ,'001',                 'S')
,(1013          ,'003',                 'X')
,(1014          ,'004',                 'S')
,(1011          ,'007',                 'X')
,(1011          ,'008',                  'S')
SELECT * FROM TABLEA
SELECT * FROM TABLEB
select a.agent_pay,count(policy_number) TableACount, sum(isnull(TableBCount,0))TableBCount
INTO #Temp
from tableA a 
LEFT JOIN
(select b.agent_pay ,count(policy_number) TableBCount
from tableB b where service_ind='x' 
group by b.agent_pay
)b on b.agent_pay = A.agent_pay
group by a.agent_pay
GO
SELECT * FROM #Temp t where t.TableACount = TableBCount
SELECT * FROM #Temp t where t.TableACount != TableBCount
```

Comment: Will i need to create #temp table?

Comment: This statement will create the #temp table. however, you'll need to assign a column name to the count.  Every column in a temp table must be named.

Comment: Just one more thing if the count does not match,the non-matched records will go into another temporary table.Can u help me with it?

Comment: You can two different query to get matched and unmatched data and push to corresponding table

Comment: The above query is giving me the no.of policies against the agent.But I want the exact policy number which are matching in respect to the agent.

Comment: These query is perfect,but I need the list of policies against the agent which are matching

Comment: The scenario should be like these if the count mismatches it will go into the error table,if the count matches it will check every agent with policy number in TableB with respect to TableA